# How do I remove specific responses from a column?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which one of the columns has three options: "No Delay","Significant Delay", and "Unknown". I want to remove the "Unknown" option from this column and recreate my dataframe.

I tried this:
toRemove="Unknown"

```
data.frame(lapply(myData, function(communicationDelay) factor(as.character(communicationDelay), levels = levels(communicationDelay)[levels(communicationDelay) != toRemove])))
```

When I open up the data in the data viewer, I still see the "Unknown" option.

I also tried:

toRemove="Unknown"

```
mynewData = data.frame(lapply(myData, function(communicationDelay) factor(as.character(communicationDelay), levels=levels(communicationDelay)[levels(communicationDelay) != toRemove])))
```

This gives me NA's for ten columns!

Sorry if this is not particularly clear - this is my first stackoverflow post. I can add more details if they are needed!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To make your question reproducible, could you share a sample of your dataset? Just some rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `!=` in `subset` to filter the rows to remove the value defined in 'toRemove' to be removed from the dataset and as it is a `factor`, the `levels` would still be present as unused levels unless we update with `droplevels` to remove those unused levels

```
dat <- droplevels(subset(myData, col1 != toRemove))
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly! If it's not too much of a bother, could you explain why my methods didn't work? I'm trying to improve my understanding of coding!

Answer (score 1):

**dplyr Solution**

`library(dplyr)`

**data**

`dataframe = tibble(delay = c("No Delay", "Significant Delay", "Unknown"))`

You can remove the unwanted entries by using the `filter()` function.

`newdataframe = dataframe %>%
    filter(delay != "Unknown")`